# Size of iAd on landscape iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iad

What are the supposed point size of iAd banners on iPhone as of now? I see quite some deprecated code in the reference itself. It's hard to find any exact information here. Are all banners 320x50 points regardless of orientation?

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html) specifically says at this time:

> iAd supports different banner sizes for portrait and landscape apps.
>   The exact size of advertisements depends on the device the banner is
>   being shown on. On an iPhone, a portrait advertisement is 320 x 50
>   points and 480 x 32 points for a landscape advertisement. On an iPad,
>   a portrait advertisement is 768 x 66 points and 1024 x 66 points for a
>   landscape advertisement. In the future, additional sizes may be
>   exposed by iAd.

**I strongly believe that documentation, while being still online, is outdated.**

And I have never gotten a 480x32 banner in my iPhone app, AFAIK.

Comment: I just realized that iOS 9.1 beta 3 forces landscape ads of a seemingly size of fullwidth-32 points, clearly different from iOS 9.0 and past. I have yet to confirm the beta docs about this. The width in my case was 568, because I used an iPhone 5s for testing iOS 9.1 beta. It might go full width on other devices too.

Comment: Here is the docs on 9.1. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@ADAdType It specifically still says device-width and height 32 for landscape ads. It seems like that actually never worked, until 9.1.